# How to disable error message sent by command "ping"?

Tags: bash, shell

I wrote a simple ping sweeper using bash script. I also use grep command to filter out the result I want. The problem is, the console keep printing out error message: "ping: recvmsg: No route to host" no matter what grep command I tried. I tried to write the output into a file, and there is no error message inside the file but they still appear on the console. I want to know what causes the console to print out error message like that and how to disable it, thanks.

Here is the script I wrote.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for ip in $(seq 1 254); do
#ping -c 1 10.11.1.$ip | grep -v "recvmsg" | grep "bytes from" | cut -d " " -f 4 | cut -d ":" -f 1 &
ping -c 1 10.11.1.$ip | grep -v "recvmsg" |grep -v "ping" |  grep "bytes from"  | cut -d " " -f 4 | cut -d ":" -f 1| sort -d >> report &
done
wait
```

And here is the error message

```
ping: recvmsg: No route to host
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the redirectors for stderr (standard error) you only need put this at the end of your command `2> error.log`

```
#!/bin/bash
for ip in $(seq 1 254); do
#ping -c 1 10.11.1.$ip | grep -v "recvmsg" | grep "bytes from" | cut -d " " -f 4 | cut -d ":" -f 1 &
ping -c 1 10.11.1.$ip 2> error.log | grep -v "recvmsg" |grep -v "ping" |  grep "bytes from"  | cut -d " " -f 4 | cut -d ":" -f 1| sort -d >> report   &
done
wait
```

Comment: Use shell brace expansion `{1..254}` instead of `seq` command.